# Forge Texture not rendering

Tags: java, json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm modding forge mods and my items won't render. Here is the error:

> [16:14:07] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant skycastle:itemskygem#inventory for item "skycastle:itemskygem", normal location exception: 
>   net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model skycastle:item/itemskygem with loader VanillaLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:336) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:156) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:122) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:541) [Minecraft.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:387) [Minecraft.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
>       at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:?]
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: skycastle:models/item/itemskygem.json
>       at net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:69) ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:65) ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModel(ModelBakery.java:334) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.access$1600(ModelLoader.java:126) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:937) ~[ModelLoader$VanillaLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
>       ... 25 more
>   [16:14:07] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant skycastle:itemskygem#inventory for item "skycastle:itemskygem", blockstate location exception: 
>   net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model skycastle:itemskygem#inventory with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:153) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadItemModels(ModelLoader.java:344) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadVariantItemModels(ModelBakery.java:175) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:156) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:122) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:541) [Minecraft.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:387) [Minecraft.class:?]
>       at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
>       at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:?]
>   Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:78) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1253) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
>       at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:149) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
>       ... 25 more

Here are useful files...
ItemSkygem.json

```
{
  "parent": "item/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "skycastle:items/skygem"
  }
}
```

ModItems.java

```
package rektek249.skycastle.init;


import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import rektek249.skycastle.items.ItemSkygem;

public class ModItems {

public static Item skygem;



public static void init(){
    skygem = new ItemSkygem().setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.MATERIALS);
}
public static void register(){
    GameRegistry.register(skygem);
}
public static void registerRenders(){
    registerRender(skygem);
}
private static void registerRender(Item item){
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName(), "inventory"));
}
```

}

Sorry for the formatting it was formatted correctly in intellij but it went wrong here....
Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error log I take that the `ResourceLocation` it tries to load is

> skycastle:itemskygem

and your file is named

> ItemSkygem.json

, but the file would need to be named `itemskygem.json` as it is case-sensitive as far as i know, also is the file in the right folder it should be *`resource_root`*`/assets/skycastle/models/item`?

Maybe the [Forge Documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will also help.

Additional Note:

- You might want to use `ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(...)` to register your ModelResourceLocation.

An example for such proxy can be found in the Mod I am working on:
 - [Declaration](https://github.com/BB20101997/MBMA/blob/master/src/main/java/de/webtwob/mbma/MultiblockMaschineAutomation.java#L24) of the proxy
 - [Common](https://github.com/BB20101997/MBMA/blob/master/src/main/java/de/webtwob/mbma/client/proxy/ClientProxy.java) implementation
 - [Client](https://github.com/BB20101997/MBMA/blob/master/src/main/java/de/webtwob/mbma/common/proxy/CommonProxy.java) implementation